# How to print full name in reference list using apacite

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

I'm writing my masters thesis, using the apacite package to create my reference list. I have apacite working properly and both the citations and the reference list work just fine. 
However, my supervisors insist that I list the full names in the reference list, in stead of using initials.
I could use author={{...}} in BibTex to force-print the full name, but then it gets sorted alphabetically on first name (which is not what I want).

Does anyone know how to do this, without messing up the correct order of references?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[includecorporate]{apacite}
\begin{document}  
%Here's a nearly complete thesis with correct citations in the proper apa-style, like \cite{Anderson}.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{scriptie}
\end{document}
```

For Bibtex (scriptie.bib):

```
@book{Anderson,
author={Benedict Anderson},
title={Title},
year={2014}
}

@book{Benedictus,
author={Anders Benedictus},
title={Title2},
year={1402}
}
```

Will print as:

> Anderson, B. (2014). Title
>
> Benedictus, A. (1402). Title2

Putting brackets around the full author name will print as:

> Anders Benedictus (1402). Title2
>
> Benedict Anderson (2014). Title

But i'd like it printed like this:

> Benedict Anderson (2014). Title
>
> Anders Benedictus (1402). Title2

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please edit your post and add source code ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) of what you have tried so far? It would help the solvers to actually start experimenting with your example.

Comment: Any news on that? I'm currently experiencing the same problem after switching to apacite.

Answer (score 4):

(Aside: I noticed your posting from almost four months ago only just now. In the meantime you are probably long done with the Master's thesis. Hopefully, though, the following answer will turn out to be useful for others who also need to accomplish the task you've outlined.)

You could proceed as follows:

- First, find the file `apacite.bst` in your TeX distribution, and make a copy of this file named, say, `myapacite.bst`. (Do not edit the original file directly.)
- Open `myapacite.bst` in a text editor; the editor program you use for your tex files will do fine.
- Find the following block of code (starting, likely, around line 675 in the file):

  ```
  FUNCTION {sort.name.format.classic} { "{ll{}}{  f{}}{  vv{}}{  jj{}}" }

  FUNCTION {cite.name.format.classic} { "{ll}" }

  FUNCTION {author.name.format.classic} { "{ll}{, f{\BPBI }.}{ vv}{, jj}" }

  FUNCTION {index.name.format.classic} { "{ll}{, f{\BPBI }.}{ vv}{, jj}" }

  FUNCTION {sort.name.format} { "{vv{}}{ll{}}{  f{}}{  jj{}}" }

  FUNCTION {cite.name.format} { "{vv }{ll}" }

  FUNCTION {cite.initials.name.format} { "{f{\BPBI }.~~}{vv }{ll}{ jj}" }

  FUNCTION {author.name.format} { "{vv }{ll}{, f{\BPBI }.}{, jj}" }

  FUNCTION {editor.name.format} { "{f{\BPBI }.~~}{vv }{ll}{ jj}" }

  FUNCTION {index.name.format} { "{vv }{ll}{, f{\BPBI }.}{, jj}" }
  ```

  In this code block, replace (a) both instances of `f{}` with `ff{}`, (b) both instances of `{ff~~}` with `{ff }`, and (c) all six instances of `f{\BPBI }.` with `ff`. No period (aka "full stop" or "dot") after `ff`, anywhere.
- On line 2067 or so of the file, there should be the instruction

  ```
  FUNCTION {initials.with.space.name.format} { "{f.}" }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
  FUNCTION {initials.with.space.name.format} { "{ff}" }
  ```
- Save the file `myapacite.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- Start using the new style file by replacing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` with `\bibliographystyle{myapacite}`. After making the switch, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer by Mico is perfect. I just want to highlight that the order of replacement is actually

1. both instances of `f{}` with `ff{}`
2. List item all six instances of
   `f{\BPBI }.` with `ff`. No period (aka "full stop" or "dot") after `ff`, anywhere.
3. both instances of `{ff~~}` with `{ff }`

In this case the order matters ;)