# apacite: How to remove the period after the names in the reference list

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

The period after the names is not a problem if you use initials, for instance:

Austin, J. (1960)

But my supervisor likes the full names in the reference list, so I used the instructions in [How to print full name in reference list using apacite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171371/how-to-print-full-name-in-reference-list-using-apacite)

Now, I got things like this:

Austin, John. (1960)

I would like to remove the period after that, but I cannot find where to change this in apacite.bst

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Your query is not addressed by the earlier posting you referenced. Please rephrase your query to make clear that it's a new query.